# Using Codeigniter, how to use get_where, but not include certain rows?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

The function that I am trying to make pulls from the database 6 of the most recent events.  I then want to test if the events are related to each other by a certain parameter (i have figured out this function), but then want to delete the repeats from the array and add the next recent event.

For example, say I have events #1-6.  Event #3 is related to event #1.  I then want to remove event #3 from the array and then add into the array event #7.  Once that is done, I want to check events, #1,2,4,5,6,7 to ensure that there are no repeats again.  I am trying to continue this process until every event is unique.

This is my current code:

```
public function get_user_events($limit=6, $offset= 0) 
    {
        $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
        $event = $this->db->order_by("time_initiated","desc")
        ->get_where("events",array("user_id" => $user->id), $limit, $offset)
        ->result_array();
        $noduplicates = FALSE;
        while(!$noduplicates) {
        foreach ($event as $a) {
            if(test_if_repeated($a, $event)) { remove from array; $noduplicates = true } 
        }
        // somehow need to refresh the list to get that 7th element
        }
        return $event;
    }
```

Comment: You ought to store the *relationships* between events in such a way that your *relational database management system* can easily determine those which are "duplicates" of others.  Then this operation will involve a single query and not require unnecessary data to be expensively transferred to PHP for further examination, only then to be discarded.

Comment: currently i have it in my database so that each event has a field with the id of the previous event and the next event, creating a linked list of the related events.  Is there any way I could use that to help, or is there some other way you would suggest changing the database?

Comment: Unlike some other RDBMS, MySQL doesn't support recursive functions - and therefore it is not well suited to your "adjacency list" model for storing hierarchical data; consider the "nested sets" or "transitive closure" models instead.

Comment: this question is only for a very small portion of the product and only needs to be used in one spot.  it would be very inconvenient to completely change the structure of the database.  do you know of a temporary workaround?

Comment: You might store the "root" event of each hierarchy instead of (or in addition to) its adjacent parent: when adding a new record, one only needs to copy the root value from the immediate parent.  Then your problem in this case is reduced to filtering for those events that are their own root.

Comment: great suggestion! i currently do have a function that gets the root, so I will compare the root to the other events.  i don't really have to worry about efficiency as only a few events can be linked together.  now that I have the answer (i am kind of new to stackoverflow), since this is in the comments do i delete the question or just leave it here?

Comment: Well, whilst that suggestion is probably the correct solution to *your problem* it doesn't really answer the question "Using Codeigniter, how to use get_where, but not include certain rows?" (which is why I haven't posted it as an answer).  If you no longer need that question answered, by all means delete the question.  Or else leave it open for someone else to provide a more directly relevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be more efficient to retrieve more records than you need and then handle all of the "related" and "duplicate" stuff - then just return the number of records that you need.

For example, retrieve the latest 30 events (arbitrary number). Then, do your magic with the "related" and "duplicate" records. Let's say you're left with 24 records - just return the most recent 6 out of that list.

Retrieving and handling 30 events versus 6 events has virtually no performance hit.